# MobileConnect - No way to update mobile number, therefore deleting priority 2 numbers?

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect

According to Salesforce Support, there is no way to overwrite the existing number on subscribers in mobile connect. By uploading an existing subscriberkey with priority 1 and a new number, this will get added as the primary number - but the old one will still exist as part of me.

In the short run, this is not an issue. But in the long run, given that numbers are recycled, we need a maintenance job to clear out priority 2 numbers.

Does any of you have experience of this via the API ? (indicated by the support team). I cannot find a documented way, when investing the mobile connect apis https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/using-the-mobileconnect-api.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The support came back with a more definitive reply:

*"I have checked your concerns with the team and they have explained that each MobileNumber associated with a particular contact would log the information about things sent to it under the MobileNumber that they had come from. As there can be multiple MobileNumbers per contact that information would just be MobileNumber specific but yes, at the contact level, it would be associated in a way with the same contact.


**We (Support) are also aware of these flaws and limitations and all we can do is encourage customers to log these as Ideas in the IdeaExchange portal** so they can be taken into consideration for future implementation. 
https://success.salesforce.com/ideaSearch?filter=Marketing+Cloud"*

So seems nothing can be done I'm afraid :(

Comment: Inclined to agree with your frustrations, Kenneth. Your use case is pretty extreme and very expensive these days.

Comment: Wouldn't say it's expensive, as it is simply not doable :-) I'm trying to confer with legal departments with the client, in order to determine if we can hit any roadblocks here. Hoping we wont :)

Comment: @KennethWagner this is three years old. Have you found a way to clear out mobile number?

Comment: I'm trying with the API, but seems it won't let me set an empty value

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/api-explorer/sfmc/contacts/patch-contacts-v1-contacts

Comment: @garek007 believe Doug below managed to find a way via SSJS ? But Haven’t looked at this particular theme in ages - so answer might be outdated

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you're trying to answer a question that doesn't need resolving. SFMC maintains these priority 2 addresses in order to suppress sends to stopped numbers. SFMC doesn't know who the ultimate individual that's got that SIM in their phone is. As you point out, this isn't an issue in the short run. Your customer's no longer using that number or that's what they've told you. But is it a problem worth expending many clock cycles over for the long run? If you consider your average consumer rotates their mobile number every five years and your market penetration in terms of what percentage of all mobile numbers in your market are in MobileConnect is something akin to 0.00001%... collisions will happen, but this is only Marketing. So, why are you bothered about deleting these records?

Comment: Hey Andrew - you're absolutely right, that it might be more theoretical than practical - however, given the technical structure of marketing cloud right now, in order to send an SMS (e.g. a transactional sms) via Journey Builder, they need to be imported. For the solution design of our client, they are buying all phone numbers in the country and importing those to mobile connect to ensure transactional sms'es are made available. They will be sending these sms'es to 20% of the market yearly. Therefore, it's quite important for us to be able to at least identify a way to clear out priority 2

Comment: Hey Andrew - one question, i realized here. If i import a new number to me, my old number goes to priority 2. That's fine. If i then import the old number to another contact, this then becomes priority 1, correct? what happens with the old priority 2 number - you know? It shouldn't continue to be suppressed or?

Comment: I just tried - and i can see that i now have two contacts, one with my old number as priority 2 (and active), and a new contact with my old number as priority 1 (and active). Do you know the system outcomes here?

Answer (score 0):

Mobile Connect data is stored in a 'hidden' data extension called _MobileAddress.

You can check the CustomerKey of it in ContactBuilder or using SOAP API to retrieve all data extensions.
The data extension has the contactId field which links to a given subscriberKey.

You can alter the DE using AMPScript or SSJS using the methods provided to interact with data extensions.

Comment: But how do you overwrite / delete a mobile number stored as priority 2 ? :)

Comment: Using ServerSideJavaScript:  `var mobileConnectDE = DataExtension.Init("<external key>");
     var contactID = <youtContactId>;
  
    mobileConnectDE.Rows.Update({_MobileNumber:"<mobile number to update>"}, ["_ContactID"], [contactID]);`

Comment: Hmm.. the recommended process is to use automation studio to import from a DE, but you would suggest using SSJS to do it Instead, to handle the update pf excisting subscribers?

Comment: You can create a Script that changes the data of the subscribers you need. This script could run right after the DE Import.

Comment: @Keneth, the sample I wrote is for updating a mobile, but you can either change its Priority or the Status to Inactive as well.

Comment: yeah, but the thing is i don't want to change it's status or priority - i want to, ideally, delete the mobile number from the subscriber in mobile connect as a whole. This can be done in two ways: 1) Overwriting existing number upon import, which SF Support says is impossible, or 2) deleting all numbers that aren't priority 1. Makes sense?
My understanding from SF support is that if we use anything to change a priority, the system will still store the number as there currently isn't an API for deleting a mobile number?

Comment: You may have a look at the documentation of the Remove function which will delete the row you want: http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/server_side_javascript/server_side_javascript_syntax_guide/core_library_server_side_javascript_functions/data_extension_server_side_javascript_functions/rows/remove/

Comment: Hey SebOB - i can see where you're going. But the remove is targeted at a DE - and i need to remove a line at the subscriber level (core mobile connect data). But, are you suggesting that mobile connect is actually stored in a DE that we can manipulate using SSJS and the remove function? (i.e. load all or remove all rows with a priority 2?)

Comment: But, are you suggesting that mobile connect is actually stored in a DE that we can manipulate using SSJS and the remove function? Yes I 'suggest' that MobileConnect contacts are stored in a DE, also MobilePush (you can google _PushAddress).

Comment: @KennethWagner I have been trying this also, and found using SSJS does seem to work when using Rows.Remove, so _MobileAddress is certainly editable.